# Predicate logic interpretation modelling

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I'm totally new to predicate logic and I need to make an interpretation that will be true for both formulas:

$$
\varphi = \forall x \forall y (\forall z(E(z,x)\Leftrightarrow E(z,y))\Rightarrow x=y)
$$
$$
\psi = \forall z \exists w \forall y \forall x ((E(x,y) \wedge E(y,z)) \Rightarrow E(x,w))
$$

According to my assignment, i have such domain:
$$
U=\{a,b\}
$$
$$
|[E]| = \{(a,a),(a,b)\}
$$

My idea was set predicate symbol E this way.

$$
E(x,y)\:\:=\:\:x !=y
$$

Did i do it right?

Comment: Not clear... if you have the domain and the interpretation of the binary predicate symbol $E$, all it is done ! you have only to check if the suggested interpretation satisfy the formulas.

Comment: This is indeed very confusing. What do you mean by $E(x,y)\:\:=\:\:x !=y$? Do you mean $E(x,y):= x \not = y$? ... but you already have an interpretation for $E$ ... and it is not $x \not = y$, since $(a,a) \in [E]$.